# JS variables and calculations failling;

Tags: javascript

Based on copy-engineering of someone else's code, I created the following code ([see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gsgND/3/)) :

```
//INITIAL DATA:
var geometry.id = "Norway";
var bounds = [[-5, 40], [10, 50]];

// START CALCULATIONS
// WNES for West, North, East, South.
// WNES borders' geo-coordinates (decimal degrees) 
var WNES = "",
    WNES.item = geometry.id,
    WNES.W = bounds[0][0],
    WNES.N = bounds[1][1],
    WNES.E = bounds[1][0],
    WNES.S = bounds[0][1];
// Area's geo-dimensions (decimal degrees)
var WNES.geo_width = (WNES.E - WNES.W),
    WNES.geo_height = (WNES.N - WNES.S);
// add a 5% padding on all WNES sides.
var WNESplus.W = WNES.W - WNES.geo_width * 0.05,
    WNESplus.N = WNES.N + WNES.geo_height * 0.05,
    WNESplus.E = WNES.E + WNES.geo_width * 0.05,
    WNESplus.S = WNES.S - WNES.geo_height * 0.05,
    WNESplus.geo_width = (WNESplus.E - WNESplus.W),
    WNESplus.geo_height = (WNESplus.N - WNESplus.S);
// calcul center geo-coordinates
var WNES.lat_center = (WNES.S + WNES.N) / 2,
    WNES.lon_center = (WNES.W + WNES.E) / 2;

//TEST:
console.log("Test" + WNESplus.N + " and " + WNESplus.geo_width);
```

This completely fails. It seems I do assignment, and semicolon use wrongly. **What is my mistake, How to prossess properly ?**

Comment: err `var geometry.id = "Norway";Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . `

Comment: I just realised you're doing the whole thing wrong - you can't put `.` in the variable name. You have to define an object first.

Comment: May the wolves who -1 the question at least explain why, so I could not do the same mistake/wrongdoing next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting object properties without creating it. You can't use dot notation in variable declaration.

Try below:

```
//INITIAL DATA:
var bounds = [[-5, 40], [10, 50]];
var geometry = {};
geometry.id = "Norway";

// START CALCULATIONS
//  WNES borders' geo-coordinates (decimal degrees for West, North, East, South borders) 
var WNES = {};
WNES.item = geometry.id,
WNES.W = bounds[0][0],
WNES.N = bounds[1][1],
WNES.E = bounds[1][0],
WNES.S = bounds[0][1];
// Area's geo-dimensions (decimal degrees)
WNES.geo_width = (WNES.E - WNES.W), 
WNES.geo_height = (WNES.N - WNES.S);
// add a 5% padding on all WNES sides.
var WNESplus = {};
WNESplus.W = WNES.W - WNES.geo_width * 0.05,
WNESplus.N = WNES.N + WNES.geo_height * 0.05,
WNESplus.E = WNES.E + WNES.geo_width * 0.05,
WNESplus.S = WNES.S - WNES.geo_height * 0.05,
WNESplus.geo_width = (WNESplus.E - WNESplus.W),
WNESplus.geo_height = (WNESplus.N - WNESplus.S);
// calcul center geo-coordinates
WNES.lat_center = (WNES.S + WNES.N) / 2,
WNES.lon_center = (WNES.W + WNES.E) / 2;

console.log("Test"+ WNESplus.N +" and "+  WNESplus.geo_width);
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsgND/5/)**

Answer (score 2):

`var` is used to declare local variables. Using it to "declare" object properties is incorrect.

You should just be doing something like:

```
WNES.geo_width = (WNES.E - WNES.W);
WNES.geo_height = (WNES.N - WNES.S);
```

That said, you appear to be trying to assign properties to a literal string. This will not work. You should probably start with:

```
var WNES = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign properties of an object (`geometry`, `WNES`, `WNESplus`) using var. You have to first initialize them as objects and then assign properties:

```
//INITIAL DATA:
var bounds = [[-5, 40], [10, 50]];
var geometry = {};
geometry.id = "Norway";

// START CALCULATIONS
//  WNES borders' geo-coordinates (decimal degrees for West, North, East, South borders) 
var WNES = {};
WNES.item = geometry.id;
WNES.W = bounds[0][0];
WNES.N = bounds[1][1];
WNES.E = bounds[1][0];
WNES.S = bounds[0][1];
// Area's geo-dimensions (decimal degrees)
WNES.geo_width = (WNES.E - WNES.W);
WNES.geo_height = (WNES.N - WNES.S);
// add a 5% padding on all WNES sides.
var WNESplus = {};
WNESplus.W = WNES.W - WNES.geo_width * 0.05;
WNESplus.N = WNES.N + WNES.geo_height * 0.05;
WNESplus.E = WNES.E + WNES.geo_width * 0.05;
WNESplus.S = WNES.S - WNES.geo_height * 0.05;
WNESplus.geo_width = (WNESplus.E - WNESplus.W);
WNESplus.geo_height = (WNESplus.N - WNESplus.S);
// calcul center geo-coordinates
WNES.lat_center = (WNES.S + WNES.N) / 2;
WNES.lon_center = (WNES.W + WNES.E) / 2;

console.log("Test " + WNESplus.N + " and " + WNESplus.geo_width);
```

Here is workign [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maximua/gsgND/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to declare a variable as an object in this format. Everything that includes dot notation or object, should be declared as var something  = {}. And as an example:

This `geometry.id = "Norway";` will 100% fail. But you can declare it as:

`var geometry = { id: "Norway"};` and follow the same template for the others as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity of your explanation~

Comment: I hope I could make it clearer. But being under the eye of your boss is not easy. I hope it helps and best of luck:)